# Getting method from request in libonion

Tags: c

I have a simple onion server:

```
int parse_input(void *p, onion_request *req, onion_response *res)
{
    const onion_request_flags flags = onion_request_get_flags(req);

    if (flags == OR_DELETE) {
        printf("got OR_DELETE\n"); // It doesnt work
    }
}

onion *o=NULL;

static void shutdown_server(int _)
{
    if (o)
    onion_listen_stop(o);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT,shutdown_server);
    signal(SIGTERM,shutdown_server);

    o=onion_new(O_POOL);
    onion_set_timeout(o, 5000);
    onion_set_hostname(o,"0.0.0.0");
    onion_set_port(o, "4711");
    onion_url *urls=onion_root_url(o);

    onion_url_add(urls, "", parse_input);
    onion_url_add(urls, "^(.*)$", parse_input);

    onion_listen(o);
    onion_free(o);
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is whenever I send a request via `curl`, I want the server to get the method of the request inside `parse_input`. So for example:

```
curl -X "DELETE" localhost:4711/
```

I want the server now to get the `DELETE` method, so I can dispatch based on it. But it does not enter the if `if (flags == OR_DELETE)`, so I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: the field is named flags, are you sure this is not a kind of bitfield? if this is the case, == is wrong, you should use &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems that you need to write

```
if ((flags & OR_METHODS) == OR_DELETE)
```

as this is a kind of bitfield

(I found an example on https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/blob/master/src/onion/handlers/webdav.c#L102 )